# Readxl: handling a column name with a space

Tags: r, readxl

I've got excel file with my data, I used "readxl" package to transport data to R. I've got several variables, one of these is called "EMPLOYEE ATTITUDE", it contais three types of grades - A, B and C. I wanted to use summary function to check what is the average hourly rate among employees who gained "A" grade.

```
Data=read_excel("Data.xls")
attach(Data)
 summary(subset(Data, EMPLOYEE ATTITUDE == A)$"HOURLY RATE")
```

and it's not working. I've tried to make variable "EMPLOYEE ATTITUDE" to be seen as a factor by commend

```
Attitude=factor(EMPLOYEE ATTITUDE)
```

**but i still see the communicat that there is no such object as "A"**!

Comment: Try replacing `"HOURLY RATE"` with `\`HOURLY RATE\`` and `EMPLOYEE ATTITUDE` with `\`EMPLOYEE ATTITUDE\``.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to make a great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). You question doesn't contain any data nor the exact error message you are facing.

Comment: Although I think that @MartinGal is on the right track, I think that usually if your column name has a blank in it,  xlsx will replace it with a period.  So try `Hourly.Rate`

Comment: Error in command 'eval(e, x, parent.frame())':object 'A' can't be found when i tried with summary(subset(Data, 'EMPLOYEE ATTITUDE' == A)$'HOURLY RATE')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could run:

```
summary(subset(Data, `EMPLOYEE ATTITUDE` == "A","HOURLY RATE"))
```

Comment: ERROR: unexpected symbol in "summary(subset(Data, EMPLOYEE ATTITUDE"

Comment: object A still can't be found, but thanks for trying

Comment: @wrzosowa look at your example. You are the one who put `A` there. I just rectified the code. I dont know what `A` is supposed to be. It can be anything. Probably its one of the columns

Comment: A is one of three possible values (A, B, C) ​​in the column named "EMPLOYEE ATTITUDE", which is filled with As, Bs, Cs

Comment: @wrzosowa Now that you have clarified the issue, check the edit